# Convert Android bitmap to Apache POI bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, apache-poi

I am trying to use an Android bitmap to be inserted into a word document (.docx file). I found out this is possible through the use of Apache POI though I am struggling to see how to transfer the image to one another.

How would I be able to convert an Android bitmap to Apache POI bitmap and vice versa?